# Extract .7Z file using sevenzip doesn't work for larger files >1GB

Tags: c#, .net, 7zip

The sevenzip extractor works fine and its good to extract small .7Z files. The same code when used to extract large file(1gb), getting the below exception.

[image]

```
SevenZipExtractor extractor = new SevenZipExtractor(@"\\Sourcepath\test_20191024143230.7z");
if (extractor.Check())
{
    using (var tmp = new SevenZipExtractor(@"\\DestinationPath\test"))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < tmp.ArchiveFileData.Count; i++)
        {
            tmp.ExtractFiles(@"C:\Users\ot97813\RPC_CodeBase\UnZip File\ExtractPath\", tmp.ArchiveFileData[i].Index);
        }
    }
}
```

looked in all websites and I didn't find this doesn't support extraction of larger files.
Note: The file is not encrypted or password protected.

Comment: Maybe, just maybe, 7Zip encountered an OutOfMemoryException and threw its own general exception

Comment: Try with System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive, using (ZipArchive archive = ZipFile.OpenRead(zipPath))
        {
            foreach (ZipArchiveEntry entry in archive.Entries)
            {entry.ExtractToFile(destinationPath)}}

Comment: @SilentTremor, using the System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive, the exception "End of Central Directory record could not be found." is been thrown for .7z files. This is the case for smaller files even that was successfully extracted using 7zip.

Comment: My bad, that make sense, it's not a valid zip archive, I'll try to see if System.IO.Compression can be used for 7Zip

Comment: System.IO,Compresion is not a solution, I mean you can write custom extractor for LZMA, but I tested with SevenZipExtractor and it's all good with zips over 1 gb

Comment: @Programming post the exception text, not images of the dialog box. Click on `Copy exception detail to the clipboard` and paste the text in the question itself. That text includes the call stack which will show you which method raised that exception and which chain of calls led to it.

Comment: BTW if you use `foreach` you won't need ` tmp.ArchiveFileData[i]` to get the item

Comment: The less obvious explanation is the obvious one: the .7z file is corrupted.  If you created it in code as well then you must make sure to explicitly delete the .7z file if anything goes wrong.

Comment: Which library are you using? The one in NuGet doesn't have such methods

Comment: Did you use [this dead project's code](https://github.com/tomap/SevenZipSharp) ? Or [this fork](https://github.com/squid-box/SevenZipSharp)? Perhaps the old code does have memory issues and the fork hasn't fixed them yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an answer, just a proof [SevenZipExtractor](https://github.com/adoconnection/SevenZipExtractor)  that is working.

```
using System;
using SevenZipExtractor; // https://github.com/adoconnection/SevenZipExtractor
using ByteSizeLib; // https://github.com/omar/ByteSize

namespace ConsoleAppSevenZipExtractor
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (ArchiveFile archiveFile = new ArchiveFile(@"C:\test.7z"))
            {
                foreach (var entry in archiveFile.Entries)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"{entry.FileName} with {ByteSize.FromBytes(entry.Size)}");

                    // extract to file to current path
                    entry.Extract(entry.FileName);
                }
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

7Zip Archive used has around 2 Gb

Console output:

> text.txt with 88.13 KB
>
> video.mp4 with 1.96 GB
>
> promo.jpg with 56.98 KB

On bin/debug files are extracted

Comment: Thanks lot for help. Between I have also tried SevenZIpExtractor as well earlier with no success. I was getting the exception "Unable to open Archive"

Comment: StackTraceDetails: at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)

Comment: at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()

Comment: your archive is corrupt or is not a valid 7zip